# Transparent windows in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, themes

Is it possible to assign transparency to windows in Ubuntu like in Windows 7 and Windows 8 themes? Also can we change themes in Ubuntu 12.04 other than Ambiance and Radiance? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

About transparency, please try out [this tutorial](http://www.jameswigley.com/2012/04/27/making-ubuntu-unity-look-beautiful-by-enabling-transparency/).
To sum up: you should play around with `compiz`. Run `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager compiz-plugins` in your console to install required packages (it will also install `compiz` itself, by resolving dependencies). Then run `ccsm` command in your terminal. It will show graphical tool with compiz preferences.You may find transparency (and many other) settings there.

If you are looking for themes for Unity, [this](http://gnome-look.org/) may be a place to start. Anything marked as GTK 3.x should work with Unity. You should put downloaded files in `/usr/share/themes` and `/usr/share/icons`.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Regarding the tutorial: link-only answers are generally discouraged, as the answer becomes useless if the link dies.  Could you edit your question to summarize the tutorial?